# SharePoint disk performance using SharePoint on Azure

Tags: 2013, performance, azure, hosting

What are your experiences with disk speed on azure?  I've done a number of IO benchmark tests on an XL VM with extra partitioned data drives (partitioning SQL logs/data) and find that disk read speed/throughput is great but write is very slow.  Installing the SharePoint 2013 bits took almost 2 hours itself! This leads me to believe that the platform is not ready for production SharePoint hosting.  Anyone have any similar experiences?  Ideas to increase performance?

Comment: Being a hosted environment the best I can offer is call and yell at Microsoft :-/ slowness has definitely been a problem with Azure/SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

Surprised that it took 2 hours to install SharePoint. Was it a media that had SP1 or some of the CU updates slipsteamed?

I work for a Vendor and few have done a variety of SharePoint , Websites and Custom Apps that you SQL VM's and the disk performance has been pretty good.

If your SharePoint deployment requires higher specs for Write operations you could look at the new D or G series VM's that are available on Azure. I think we still need to wait for the G series.

SharePoint writes are mainly at the SQL level, so try adding multiple disks at the SQL level and architecture the SQL platform for performance.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748824(v=office.15).aspx

Hope that helps,